# What is meant by urlencoded request?

Tags: http, express, body-parser

Actually I am working with express. I encountered express.json() and express.urlencoded() in a project. I want to know what is urlencoded request?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this refers to a body whose `Content-Type` is [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type), e.g.:

```
firstname=John&lastname=Smith
```

as opposed to a body that's JSON-encoded, e.g.:

```
{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith"}
```